# Excel "ISBLANK" function With "IF" function

Tags: excel

I have multiple Excel workbooks in which there are many columns. There will be a column in English and a column in Spanish.  What I am trying to do is compare the two columns to see if the Spanish column does indeed have translated text from English. That's easy enough:

```
IF(A2=C2, "NOT TRANSLATED", "TRANSLATED")
```

However, there are hundreds of cells that simply do not have values in both the English and Spanish columns. So the formula I used above will say "Yes, these are technically the same value even though they're null, so no translation has been done". This is causing it to seem like there are far too many "NOT TRANSLATED" values than there actually are. This is what I tried:

```
IF(A2=C2, "NOT TRANSLATED", "TRANSLATED", IF(ISBLANK(A2)=TRUE, "NULL VALUE", "CHECK VALUE"))
```

That gives me an error though.

I am thinking that I need to have a function that first checks to see if the cell has a value to begin with. If it does, then the formula should proceed to check to see if the two cells have identical values or not. If either cell does not have a value, then it should return "NULL VALUE". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wooo!!!  With a little help from you guys I got it.  It looks like this:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(A2)=TRUE; ISBLANK(B2)=TRUE); "NULL"; IF(OR(ISBLANK(A2)=TRUE; ISBLANK(B2)=TRUE); "NOT TRANSLATED"; IF(A2=B2; "NOT TRANSLATED"; "TRANSLATED")))
```

That one was a monster.

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively giving the `IF` function 4 parameters with that second formula. `IF` accepts at least 1 mandatory parameter (the condition) and then 2 optional parameters (what to do if it returns TRUE or FALSE).

Instead you need to nest your `IF` conditions with something like:

```
IF(A2=C2, IF(ISBLANK(A2)=TRUE, "NULL VALUE", "CHECK VALUE"), "TRANSLATED")
```

Which checks to see if A2=C2, if it is then it checks to see if A2 is blank, if it is (and A2=C2 remember) then it returns "NULL VALUE", if it isn't (but A2 is still equal to C2) then it reurns "CHECK VALUE" and if A2 isn't equal to C2 then it returns "TRANSLATED".

Obviously you might want to tweak this for your problem.

Comment: You might also want to decide which way round you check your columns, as the above will be true if A2 & C2 are both blank.

Comment: @DanKelly Yep. The main point is just that the IF formula only accepts (up to) 3 parameters though. I wasn't going to go into too much detail about nested boolean logic.

Comment: The ISBLANK() function returns a boolean. Using IF(ISBLANK(A2)=TRUE, ... when IF(ISBLANK(A2), ... is sufficient seems redundant.

Comment: So is it even possible for me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might find this formula helpful, it will check for a null value in either column

```
{=IF(OR(A1:B1=""),"Null Value",IF(A1=B1,"Not Translated","Translated"))}
```

Leave out the curly braces and enter the function using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can drag that down for the following results

```
a   a   Not Translated
b   c   Translated
d       Null Value
    e   Null Value
        Null Value
f   f   Not Translated
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(OR(LEN(A2)=0,LEN(C2)=0),"IS NULL",IF(A2=C2, "NOT TRANSLATED", "TRANSLATED"))
```